# What is the best alternative to nested for loops?

Tags: javascript, optimization, nested-loops

I'm trying to optimize this code, which mesures the length of 2 points in space and draws a line if the length is apropiate. The thing is that it is very slow (mainly on smartphone).
Is there anything I could do to make it faster? Like avoiding some innecesary code. I've been trying to for weeks.

```
   this.dots.forEach(p => {
      this.dots.forEach(q => {
        // Using  x * x instead of Math.pow for efficiency
        let z = Math.sqrt((q.x - p.x) * (q.x - p.x) + (q.y - p.y) * (q.y - p.y));

        if(p != q && z < this.STRING_MAX && z > this.STRING_MIN) {

         // Background's oposite color
          if(p.y > p5.windowHeight + 45) {
            p5.stroke(0, this.transp);
          } else {
            p5.stroke(255, this.transp);
          }
          p5.line(p.x, p.y, q.x, q.y);
        }
      });
    });
```

This is how it looks (it doesn't only draw the lines, that's why it's slower):
[Neural Fuse](https://neural-fuse.netlify.app)

[Gitlab project](https://gitlab.com/neural-fuse/neural-fuse)

Comment: You could factor out the `Math.sqrt()` call and compare `z` to the square of those two limits.

Comment: Also if you're doing a combinatorial process that involves pairing members of a list with all other members of a list, the looping mechanism itself is not the core problem; it's the basic process that's slow.

Comment: For sure you could memoize the results of the calculation.  That would avoid recomputing things you already computed the value of.  https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-memoization/

Comment: You might not have to check EVERY point against EVERY other point. Maybe first filter a sub-list of points that are in the same part of the screen?

Comment: @Pointy the first thing I didn't quite get it, the second thing is where the problem is, I understand that, and Kokodoko 's improvement might be very good.

Comment: You can look at "Quad Trees", it's an algorithm that does a pre-selection of objects that are near each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the Math function could be done within the if() test loop as that would ignore p == q items.

However, for situations such as this, I would suggest that it is more typical to have two loops - the outer loop going from 0 to the penultimate item and the inner loop going from the outer loop's counter+1 to the last item:

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length - 1; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < items.length; j++) {
    // check values at i and j
  )
}
```

This way, i and j will never be the same and you never need to iterate over the entire array for every instance of i.

Comment: The first thing I didn't think about it. The second thing so smart! Thanks!

Comment: That's actually the technique for finding combinations where the order of the results doesn't matter - ie, ab and ba are considered the same.

Comment: Additionally, you only really need to do something with a combination if Math.abs(q.x-p.x) AND Math.abs(q.y-p.y) are less than your "appropriate" distance.  This will immediately eliminate any pairs that already too far apart.

Comment: You mean in order to not make the execution of the ones that are already far from each other in one axis and then the other, right?

Comment: Yep - if either side of the shorter sides of a right-angle triangle is greater than your appropriate length, the hypotenuse value must also be greater than that value.  a² + b² = c² so for the sqrt of c² to be less than your max, a and b must also be less than your max.

Comment: Sorry, one exception to that would be if either, but not both, x's or y's are the same - so the difference is 0.  Say your max is 100, then (100² * 0²) is ok, but (101² * 0²) or (100² * 1²) is not